# How to get percentage lineSpacing of UIFont? (to calculate a percentage value)

Tags: ios, uikit, foundation, core-text, uifont

Is there a way to set [`lineSpacing`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle/1528742-linespacing) property of [`NSParagraphStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsparagraphstyle) / [`NSMutableParagraphStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle) attribute of an [`NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring) object to a percentage of the font's base/original `lineSpacing`?

`lineSpacing` is a property of `NSParagraphStyle` rather than `UIFont` so it's not possible to know what the original `lineSpacing` for a font is.

As a reference, here's a little extension I wrote for assigning `lineSpacing` to a `UILabel` (accumulative, does not cause information loss on the label's attributedString):

```
import UIKit

extension UILabel {
    /// -important: must be called after setting the `text` property so the computed NSRange would be valid
    func setLineSpacing(with lineSpacing: CGFloat) {
        // get safe string
        guard let textString = self.text, !textString.isEmpty
            else { return }

        // get the range
        let entireRange: NSRange = (textString as NSString).range(of: textString)
        guard entireRange.isValidNSRange(within: textString)
            else { assertionFailure() ; return }

        // NSMutableAttributedText
        guard let mutableAttributedText: NSMutableAttributedString = self.attributedText?.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableAttributedString
            else { assertionFailure() ; return }

        // NSParagraphStyle
        var paragraphStyle: NSParagraphStyle? = mutableAttributedText.attribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, at: 0, longestEffectiveRange: nil, in: entireRange) as? NSParagraphStyle
        if paragraphStyle == nil {
            // why TTTAttributedLabel :(
            paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle()
        }

        // safe NSParagraphStyle
        guard let safeParagraphStyle: NSParagraphStyle = paragraphStyle
            else { assertionFailure() ; return }

        // NSMutableParagraphStyle
        guard let mutableParagraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle = safeParagraphStyle.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableParagraphStyle
            else { assertionFailure() ; return }

        // this is where the magic happens
        mutableParagraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
        mutableAttributedText.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: mutableParagraphStyle, range: entireRange)

        // assign attributed text which has all the existing attributes plus the new line spacing attribute which is inside the paragraphstyle attribute...
        self.attributedText = mutableAttributedText
    }
}

extension NSRange {
    // Is it safe to use range on the string?
    func isValidNSRange(within string: String) -> Bool {
        if self.location != NSNotFound
            && self.length > 0
            && self.location + self.length - 1 < string.length
            && self.location >= 0
        {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

I already researched the problem, found no answer on Stackoverflow. So I'm sharing my own [FWIW](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). (I wanted to include `CoreText` tag so this would be easily searchable, but my reputation does not allow me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

```
extension UIFont {
    func getLineSpacing(with percentage: CGFloat = 1) -> CGFloat {
        let lineSpacing: CGFloat = (self.lineHeight - self.pointSize)// /2

        return lineSpacing * percentage
    }
}
```

I based my solution [this article](https://belka.us/en/uilabel-line-height-in-swift/) and [this interesting Chinese article](https://www.jianshu.com/p/50b3d434cbc0). More specifically, I'm attaching screenshots of the parts I used to infer the answer:

[image: https://belka.us/en/uilabel-line-height-in-swift/]

[image: https://www.jianshu.com/p/50b3d434cbc0]