How to get the default LineSpacing of a font in SwiftUI?
I wanted to get the line spacing of a font in SwiftUI. Something like this:
let font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
font.lineSpacing  // << not possible

I am able to get the pointSize and lineHeight but don't know how to calculate the line spacing. It seems to be 2 when I tried to figure it out visually but I'm not sure.
I also tried using @Environment(\.lineSpacing) var spacing but this always returned 0. Not sure how this is used.
How can I find the line spacing of a particular font (for example, the default .body font)?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54184581/5133585

@Sweeper I tried using this formula as well but the output wasn't correct. I'll update my question with some code

@Sweeper It seems to over estimate the line spacing by some amount. Which causes it to overshoot

The .leading property is what gives line spacing.
UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body).leading  // returns ~1.712


The question included an example for a while, which had 9 lines of text. I tried using a GeometryReader to measure the full height of this text and computed the line spacing using the formula (h - (9 * lineHeight)) / 8.0. I can confirm that the result was 1.7186686197916643, which seems to correspond quite closely to the value reported in this answer.
